# Spring servlet-context.xml error with mongo

Tags: xml, spring, mongodb

I have the following spring servlet-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

and I get in eclipse the following error on the file:

> The errors below were detected when validating the file
>   "spring-mongo-1.0.xsd" via the file "servlet-context.xml".  In most
>   cases these errors can be detected by validating
>   "spring-mongo-1.0.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors
>   will only occur when spring-mongo-1.0.xsd is validated in the context
>   of servlet-context.xml.

src-resolve:Cannot resolve the name 'repository:repository'to a(n) 'type definition' componenent Location: line 110

The project still works, but I am trying to get rid of this error. Any ideas?

Comment: In other similar question I've seen that suggets to change for "spring-mongo-1.1.xsd". I think it may avoid the error but it's not the right solution while using 1.0 libraries version. Waiting for a solution.

Comment: I've solved this issue with "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @francadaval the solution was to change the link to the xsd to:

springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd